# Restrictions in asmx web services

Tags: c#, asmx

When designing ASMX web services, there is some sort of restriction on the types which you can use (Serialize/deserialize).

Can anyone let me know what these restrictions are? Can it be bypassed by just adding the serializable attribute to the code?

Comment: When you design ASMX web services, you should be aware that Microsoft now considers ASMX to be "legacy technology".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Traditional ASMX Web services use `XmlSerializer` class and stuff are [subject to the restrictions imposed by that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109318/using-net-what-limitations-if-any-are-there-in-using-the-xmlserializer), the most prominent of which is probably not being able to serialize dictionaries. It doesn't care about the `[Serializable]` attribute as `BinaryFormatter` does.