# How can I return a user defined object from ASMX Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, object, asmx

```
    [WebMethod]
    public engineer getItem()
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string tcNo="13609224456";
        var bilgiler = db.bilgilers.First(c => c.tc_kimlik_no ==tcNo);

        string adi = bilgiler.adi;
        string soyadi = bilgiler.soyadi;
        string universite = bilgiler.universite;
        engineer e = new engineer(tcNo, adi, soyadi, universite);

        return e;
    }
```

I have more than one method and I can run the webservice without error but when I call the `getItem()` method I get the following exception. How can I fix the problem?

```
[InvalidOperationException: Parametresiz oluşturucusu olmadığından MUHENDIS.Service1.engineer seri hale getirilemez.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported() +3938411
   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError) +170
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +65
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +236

[InvalidOperationException: 'getItemResult' yansıtmada bir hata oluştu.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +843
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access) +130
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, Boolean rpc, SoapBindingUse use, SoapParameterStyle paramStyle, String elementName, String elementNamespace, Boolean nsIsDefault, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean validate, Boolean openModel, String key, Boolean writeAccess) +223
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +2989
```

*Edit:* Google translates the message on the exceptions as the following:

1. MUHENDIS.Service1.engineer not a parameterless constructor be serialized.
2. 'getItemResult' to reflect the error occurred.

Comment: Guess you need a parameterless constructor for engineer

Comment: @V4Vendetta it works,but how can i define a object without constructor??

Comment: Unnamed - It would help if you post your engineer class source as well. But based on stack trace @V4Vendetta is correct.

Comment: @Unnamed - you have to define parameterless constructor, so the serializer can work with the object. If you cannot touch the object in business domain, you'll have to create another one for the webservice purposes and copy properties from business domain object to webservice object.

Comment: @Unnamed you need a **parameterless constructor** , check the link its explained there (something like `engineer(){}` )

Comment: @V4Vendetta Did you just link back to this question? I think you did :P

Comment: @JeffBridgman ooops you are right the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109318/using-net-what-limitations-if-any-are-there-in-using-the-xmlserializer

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that your engineer class is marked as serializable.

```
[Serializable]
public class engineer{ ....
```

Comment: Ddoes that attribute apply to XML serialization as well as binary serialization? I've only used it in context of binary serialization before.

Comment: Yes it applies to both [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to define getItem method like this.

```
[WebMethod]
[XmlInclude(typeof(engineer))]
public engineer getItem(){
//codes here
}
//engineer class here
```

without the XmlInclude attributes, the XmlSerializer would not be able to serialize the engineer