# class members missing from XML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

BinaryFormatter.Serialize is deprecated so I am switching to XmlSerializer. The expected behavior is that public members are serialized. If the object being serialized is `IEnumerable<T>` something different happens. Public members are not serialized and the enumerable is serialized (even if private).

```
public class Thing : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public bool flag; // ignored !
    internal int ignored; // ignored as you would expect
    private List<int> list; 
    public List<int> publicList; // ignored !
    internal Thing() 
    {
        this.list = new List<int>(); this.list.Add(456); 
        this.publicList = new List<int>(); this.publicList.Add(789); 
    }
    public void Add(int i) { this.list.Add(i); }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<int>)list).GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)list).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The result in XML Notepad...

[image]

Notice in the image `ArrayOfInt` is not even the correct identification. The invocation...

```
    var thing = new Thing();
    thing.flag = true; thing.ignored = 123;
    Serialize(thing.GetType(), thing, "TestThing.xml");
```

The helper...

```
private static void Serialize(Type t, object o, string path)
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(t);
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        s.Serialize(sw, o);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

I have tested a very similar object that lacks the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation and it appears normal and member identification is normal. I have more than one object that needs to be `IEnumerable<T>` and I am trying to avoid a rewrite of these objects. Binary serialization seemed painless so this is a surprise. What is the simplest solution to replacing binary serialization?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109318/using-net-what-limitations-if-any-are-there-in-using-the-xmlserializer

Comment: The behavior you're asking about is well-documented. See proposed duplicates for in-depth discussion about the special treatment of collection types.

Comment: @PeterDuniho from your linked answer, "a property that returns the enumeration" is the simplest alternative implementation for the target classes, possibly making XmlSerializer readily usable.